# How do I retrieve all apps schedule notification for ios

Tags: ios

Currently, I want to create the list for me to know any apps are now created the schedule notification in iPhone.

May I know how can I do it for retrieve these info in UIlocationNotification?

Comment: I don't understand your english

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to do it. Each app has own 'sandbox' and is isolated for security reasons. You can retrieve only all scheduled local notifications for your own app.